# how to test my cordova ios app using windows and iPhone

Tags: cordova-ios

I dont have MAC machine currently but the requirement is to test the cordova app using windows + iPhone.
How can I do the testing of cordova ios app using windows and iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

In order to test IOS app, regardless of Cordova or etc, you need to have a SDK called Xcode installed on your OS. XCode is only available to install on MAC and IOS.

You have numerous options to overcome this limitation. One preferred(In my own point) and simple way is to [install MAC OS using tools such VMWare on your Windows OS](https://techsviewer.com/install-macos-sierra-vmware-windows/), etc.

After installing MAC on VMWare or any other similar tools, you can easily debug and test your app.

You can read more about deployment process in XCode, here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/